# Is it possible to define specific dimens for range of API's?

Tags: java, android, xml

I used font for my whole app by addin this :

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/aviny</item>
```

into my styles.xml for AppTheme, As you know this will work on APIs +23 I think!
The problem is when I install my app in API 19 for example, my texts in app shown much bigger than that i want and that is becuz i stetted big dimension values for my font to show clearly and better.( I'm not trying to set the font for lower apis but i need to change dimens for lower apis with the default font of android studio).
The question is, is it possible to define dimens.xml for apis lower than 23? and if yes,how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

simply create a new style.xml in your values folder and put the one you have in values-v23 folder, this way you can serve diffrent style sets for different API levels